# I want integrate shopify into my mvc 4 c# application

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, shopify

I want to integrate shopify in my mvc 4 web application (c#). Is this possible as it provides REST API. But the documentation is not very useful. Is anyone can help me. How can I integrate it

Comment: they don't have API for integrating it into custom application. They have their own solution. Thanks for you help @Andrien

Comment: Your comment suggests that your query got sorted out? If that is the case then I suggest you that you post the answer yourself for the sake of completion of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they don't have API for integrating it into custom application. They have their own solution.